# Formal group law of complex cobordism

Tags: algebraic-topology, cobordism

## Background:

The underlying ring of the universal formal group law is, by a theorem of Quillen, the complex cobordism ring  $\Omega_U^*$. Let $F_u(x,y) = x+y+\sum_{i,j\geq1}a_{ij}x^iy^j,\ a_{ij} \in \Omega_U^*$ be the universal group law and denote by **FGL**($R$) be the category of formal groups laws over the ring $R$. The universal formal group law $F_u$ can be seen as an element of **FGL**($\Omega_U^*\otimes \mathbb{Q}$) and by a structure theorem for the complex cobordism ring we have an isomorphism

$\Omega_U^* \otimes \mathbb{Q} \cong \mathbb{Q}[[\mathbb{P}^1],[\mathbb{P}^2],\dots]$

where $\mathbb{P}^i$ is the complex projective space.

## Question:

Is there an explicit expression of the coefficients $a_{ij} \in \Omega_U^*\otimes\mathbb{Q}$ as polynomials in $\mathbb{Q}[[\mathbb{P}^1],[\mathbb{P}^2],\dots]$?

## References:

http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Formal_group_laws_and_genera

http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Complex_bordism

[http://people.virginia.edu/~mah7cd/Conferences/Vietnam2013/QuillenBP.pdf](http://people.virginia.edu/%7Emah7cd/Conferences/Vietnam2013/QuillenBP.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Mishenko's theorem the logarithm of the formal group law of complex cobordism over $\mathbb{Q}$ is
$$
g_u(x)=x+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{[\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^k]}{k+1}x^{k+1}
$$
By definition of logarithm,
$$
g_u(f_u(x,y))=g_u(x)+g_u(y),
$$
i.e.,
$$
f_u(x,y)=g_u^{-1}(g_u(x)+g_u(y)).
$$
In principle, the right hand side can be given an explict expression, e.g., by using [Lagrange inversion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem) to write the Taylor coefficients of $g_u^{-1}(x)$, but I will not attempt determining a closed formula for the coefficient of $x^iy^j$ in $g_u^{-1}(g_u(x)+g_u(y))$.